# Conditional expectation in Basic Linear Unobserved Effects Panel Data Model

Tags: panel-data, dataset, expected-value, model, conditional-expectation

I want to see that $ E[u_t|X_t,c] \Rightarrow E[X_t' u_t]$ in a Panel Data Models

Comment: I guess you mean how $E[U_t|X_t,c]=0 \implies E[X_t'u_t]=0$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, notice that
$$
E[U_t | X_t] = E[ E[U_t|X_t,c] ] = 0
$$
where first equality is the Law of iterated expectations and the second equality holds because $E[U_t|X_t,c]=0$.  Then,

$$
E[X_t U_t] = E[ X_t E[U_t | X_t] ] = 0
$$
where the first equality uses the law of iterated expectations and the second from the top result.

Comment: So thanks, I have a question. can i interpret $E[E[U_t|X_t,c]]=E[E[(U_t|X_t)|c]]$?